# What's wrong with this implementation of Tarjan's algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation

I've implement Tarjan's algorithm following the [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_pseudocode) however I'm experiencing a problem. What I'm trying to do is to find all strongly connected components with size greater than 1.
With smaller sized inputs everything works fine however, when tested with [input.txt](http://pastebin.com/bFUB4w8g) the algorithm starts to behave strangely - on changing the initial value of `n` (for example 1, -10, 3) the program gives different results. And that's what I cannot understand. The algorithm should not depend on the initial value since `n` is used only as time stamp. If have any idea please share it it would help me so much, thank you.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Stack;

public class GraphAlgorithms {
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> graph;
    int n;

    public GraphAlgorithms(String fileName) {
        graph = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" +");
                HashSet<String> to = new HashSet<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++)
                    to.add(tokens[i]);
                graph.put(tokens[0], to);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public GraphAlgorithms(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    private void strongConnect(String v, HashMap<String, Integer> index, 
                    HashMap<String, Integer> lowlink, Stack<String> stack, 
                    HashSet<String> inStack, ArrayList<HashSet<String>> ans) 
    {

        index.put(v, n);
        lowlink.put(v, n);
        ++n;
        stack.push(v);
        inStack.add(v);

        HashSet<String> successors = graph.get(v);

        for(String w : successors) {
            if (!index.containsKey(w)) {
                strongConnect(w, index, lowlink, stack, inStack, ans);
                if (lowlink.get(w) < lowlink.get(v))
                    lowlink.put(v, lowlink.get(w));
            }
            else if (inStack.contains(w)) {
                if (index.get(w) < lowlink.get(v))
                    lowlink.put(v, index.get(w));
            }
        }

        if (index.get(v) == lowlink.get(v)) {
            HashSet<String> connectedComponent = new HashSet<String>();
            String w;
            do {
                w = stack.pop();
                inStack.remove(w);
                connectedComponent.add(w);
            }
            while (!w.equals(v));

            ans.add(connectedComponent);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<HashSet<String>> getStronglyConnectedComponents() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> index = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> lowlink = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Stack <String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        HashSet<String> inStack = new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<HashSet<String>> ans = new ArrayList<HashSet<String>>();

        n = 0;
        for (String v : graph.keySet()) {
            if (!index.containsKey(v))
                strongConnect(v, index, lowlink, stack, inStack, ans);
        }

        return ans;
    }

    public void printComponentsLargerThanOne() {
        for (HashSet<String> component : getStronglyConnectedComponents()) {
            if (component.size() > 1) {
                for (String element : component) {
                    System.out.print(element + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphAlgorithms ga = new GraphAlgorithms("input.txt");
        ga.printComponentsLargerThanOne();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java apparently doesn't always intern objects of type `java.lang.Integer`, the line

```
if (index.get(v) == lowlink.get(v)) {
```

should be

```
if (index.get(v).equals(lowlink.get(v))) {
```